# Reading source code from a webpage in java

Tags: java, html-content-extraction

I am trying to read source code from a webpage. My java code is

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

class Testing{
public static void Connect() throws Exception{


  URL url = new URL("http://excite.com/education");
  URLConnection spoof = url.openConnection();


  spoof.setRequestProperty( "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.5; Windows NT 5.0; H010818)" );
  BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(spoof.getInputStream()));
  String strLine = "";


  while ((strLine = in.readLine()) != null){


   System.out.println(strLine);
  }

  System.out.println("End of page.");
 }

 public static void main(String[] args){

  try{

   Connect();
  }catch(Exception e){

  }
}
```

When i compile and run this code, it gives the following output:

�`I�%&/m�{J�J��t�`$ؐ@������iG#)�*��eVe]f@�흼��{���{���;�N'���?\fdl��J�ɞ!���?~|?"~�$}�>�������4�����7N�����+�ӲM�N��?J�tZfM��G�j����R��!�9�?>JgE��Ge[����ⳏ���W�?�����8������
�|8�
���������ho����0׳���|փ:--�|�L�Uο�׫��m�zt�n3��l\�w��O^f�G[�CG<�y6K��gM�rg��ǟy�Eִy����h˜��ؗ˲X���l=�ڢZ�/����(կ^O�UU6�����&�6_�`@yC}�p�y���lAH�ͯ��zF#�V�6_��}��)�v=J+�$��̤�G�Y�L�b���wS"�7�y^����Z�m���Y:ɛ���J<N_�Y=���U�f���,���y�Q2(J٩P!ͨ�i����1&F0&ૼn�?�x�T��h�Qzw�+����n�)�h��K��2����8g����⮥��A0
���1I�%����Q�Z����{��������w���?x����N�?�<d�S��۫�%a|4�j��z���k�Bak��k-�c�z�g��z���l`>���֎s^,��5��/B�{����]]����Ý�ֳ���y{�_l�8g�k�ӫ�b���"+|��(��M��^[���`J�P��_�..?������x�Z�$`������E>��느�u���E~����{媘���f�e1ͷ�QZ,�����f��e�3Jٻb�^��4��۴���>*��y��;��<렛{�l��ZfW
S@  {�]��1��Q*�����n[`�,t�?����~�n�S�u#SL��n�^��������EC��q�/�y���FE�tpm������e&��oB���z9eY��������P��IK?����̦����w�N��;�;J?����;�/��5���M���rZ��q��]��C�dᖣ��F�nd���}���A5���M�5�.�:��/�_D�?�3����'�c�Z7��}��(OI),ۏi����{�<�w�������DZ?e����'q���eY]=���kj���߬������\qhrRn���l�o-��.���k��_���oD8��GA�P�r��|$��ȈPv~Y�:�[q?�sH�� <��C��ˬ�^N�[ v(��S��l�c�C����3���E5&5�VӪL�T��۔���oQrĈ��/���#[f�5�5"�`���[���t�vm�\��.0�nh����aڌWYM
^T�|\,��퓜�L�u����B�̌�C�r������ �������'�%�{��)�);�fV�]��g,�>�C  �c2���p�4��}H���P��(�%j"�}�&�:�Oh\5I�l�氪��{�/�]�LB�l��2��I"��=��Y�|�>�֏n�������}�����~�[��'�*�O��
��:/�)�Wz�3��lo�.5�k�&����H[ji�����b������WWy}�5�֝Q�|f�����]�KjH5��}yNm�����g*�ӷ�ǣ��>��'o��泏��<���G�g���>->�xQM�����%<�|����u�.��3���[�[r���ٝ;���]4E��6[����]����1���*�8}��n�w�������ݽ����|����}|qo|�~u����w|�i�i���Z�`z�ŧ����Q}�u��!���w   �O���R9�)�~��g~߻w6��{���wd�o��/Z�uUS��݄l��I^�����>��[�U1�o�_��J��}��@�@�U�/��/?���i�7|CZT?(�2b~����c�W�c5'����EeFĿꇙ�0��T��{��W�2����/���O���YJj����K/���>��:'_l�

Other than URLs from this directory i.e. "excite.com/education" all URLs are giving correct source codes but these URLs are creating problems.

Anyone Please Help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It can be an enconding problem.

Comment: Maybe the content is compressed?

Comment: The Content-Encoding is gzip          Content-Encoding :gzip

Comment: I would have a look at HttpClient from Apache.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It works for me.

```
private static String getWebPabeSource(String sURL) throws IOException {
        URL url = new URL(sURL);
        URLConnection urlCon = url.openConnection();
        BufferedReader in = null;

        if (urlCon.getHeaderField("Content-Encoding") != null
                && urlCon.getHeaderField("Content-Encoding").equals("gzip")) {
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new GZIPInputStream(
                    urlCon.getInputStream())));
        } else {
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    urlCon.getInputStream()));
        }

        String inputLine;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
            sb.append(inputLine);
        in.close();

        return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try reading it this way:

```
private static String getUrlSource(String url) throws IOException {
        URL url = new URL(url);
        URLConnection urlConn = url.openConnection();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                urlConn.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuilder a = new StringBuilder();
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
            a.append(inputLine);
        in.close();

        return a.toString();
    }
```

and set your encoding according to the web page - notice this line:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                urlConn.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have to uncompress the content using GZIPInputStream. Then put the uncompressed stream to Input Stream and read it using BufferedReader

Use Apache HTTP Client 4.1.1

Maven dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Sample Code to parse gzip content.

```
package com.gzip.simple;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream;

import org.apache.http.Header;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

public class GZIPFetcher {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {

            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet("http://excite.com/education");
            getRequest.addHeader("accept", "application/json");

            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(getRequest);

            if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != 200) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                        + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
            }

            InputStream instream = response.getEntity().getContent();

            // Check whether the content-encoding is gzip or not.
            Header contentEncoding = response
                    .getFirstHeader("Content-Encoding");

            if (contentEncoding != null
                    && contentEncoding.getValue().equalsIgnoreCase("gzip")) {
                instream = new GZIPInputStream(instream);
            }

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    instream));

            String content;
            System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
            while ((content = in.readLine()) != null)
                System.out.println(content);

            httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```